# Function to calculate finite difference

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, finite-difference-method

I wrote a function to calculate multivariate finite difference of different orders

```
ClearAll[FiniteDifference];
FiniteDifference[expr_, xs_List, ds_List] := Block[{},
   If[Length[xs] == 0,
    expr,
    If[Length[xs] == 1,
     If[
      ds[[1]] == 0,
      expr,
      If[ds[[1]] == 1,
       (expr /. xs[[1]] -> xs[[1]] + 1) - expr,
       FiniteDifference[(expr /. xs[[1]] -> xs[[1]] + 1) - 
         expr, {xs[[1]]}, {ds[[1]] - 1}]
       ]
      ],
     FiniteDifference[FiniteDifference[expr, {xs[[1]]}, {ds[[1]]}], 
      Rest[xs], Rest[ds]]
     ]
    ]
   ];
FiniteDifference[f[x], {x}, {0}]
FiniteDifference[f[x], {x}, {1}]
FiniteDifference[f[x], {x}, {2}]
FiniteDifference[f[x, y], {x, y}, {0, 1}]
FiniteDifference[f[x, y], {x, y}, {1, 1}]

Out[123]= f[x]

Out[124]= -f[x] + f[1 + x]

Out[125]= f[x] - 2 f[1 + x] + f[2 + x]

Out[126]= -f[x, y] + f[x, 1 + y]

Out[127]= f[x, y] - f[x, 1 + y] - f[1 + x, y] + f[1 + x, 1 + y]
```

I wonder, is it correct, especially in last sample?

Comment: To answer your question, check the documentation (not very easy to find online): [tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html#1549364750) - explicit formulas are above the heading for `FiniteDifferenceDerivative`. Maybe this should be closed as "easily found in the documentation" - but it's not that easy to find, so I could also post an answer if needed (or even better: answer your own question).

Comment: Agree with @Jens. This is not easy to find. You have to already know it is there in order to know it is there! But it should solve your problems.

Comment: @Jens, I added some keywords to that notebook, so in a future version one should be able to enter relevant search queries and it should then pring up this notebook. Hope that helps a bit. Thanks.

Comment: the correct expressioms are easy enough to find http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference if you just want to validate. you of course need to divide by the deltas.

Comment: @user21 Great - thanks. That's a valuable resource, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using [`DifferenceDelta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceDelta.html) to check your answers for these examples.

---

```
In[1]:= DifferenceDelta[f[x], {x, 0}]

Out[1]= f[x]

In[2]:= DifferenceDelta[f[x], x]

Out[2]= -f[x] + f[1 + x]

In[3]:= DifferenceDelta[f[x], {x, 2}]

Out[3]= f[x] - 2 f[1 + x] + f[2 + x]

In[4]:= DifferenceDelta[f[x, y], {x, 0}, {y, 1}]

Out[4]= -f[x, y] + f[x, 1 + y]

In[5]:= DifferenceDelta[f[x, y], x, y]

Out[5]= f[x, y] - f[x, 1 + y] - f[1 + x, y] + f[1 + x, 1 + y]
```

---